# How to view dvi files with evince

Tags: file-format, evince

Evince cannot view my dvi files. Is there any way to enable dvi viewing other than further installing Ubuntu TeX Live packages?

Opening it from the desktop gives *document has incorrect format*; using the terminal gives

> warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c

(If you are using TeX Live installed from TUG, you can just use the provided xdvi to view dvi files.)

Comment: Evince requires some dvi libraries that are provided by the `texlive-binaries` and `texlive-common` packages. The same problem occurs if you manually install a newer texlive release. Evince will not like the libraries provided unless they are in the standard location.

Comment: Okular worked without TeX Live: `sudo aptitude install -y okular okular-extra-backends`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evince requires some dvi libraries that are provided by the `texlive-binaries` and `texlive-common` packages. The same problem occurs if you manually install a newer texlive release. Evince will not like the libraries provided unless they are in the standard location. (Or you will have to install evince manually as well)